# How to change width and height of an image respectively by only changing one of them in python(pygame)

Tags: python, image, transform, pygame-surface

Is there is any method available in **pygame** through which if I only change the width of an image, its height automatically modifies *respectively according to the scale*.

I know I can do this by first getting original dimensions of an image and then using ratios to change x-axis and y-axis height *respectively according to the scale*. But this is a long method as I have to take ratios two times and it make things a little complicated.

If there is a short method to do this or there is some builtin function, please let me know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code:
1) YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))
2) SPACESHIP_HEIGHT, SPACESHIP_WIDTH = 500 , 1000  
(3) pygame.transform.scale( YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_HEIGHT, SPACESHIP_WIDTH)

Here I loaded an image and transformed both its width  and height. What I want is to modify both width and height by the same ratio by only changing one of them. IF see the values of height and width the ratio between them is ( 1:2 ). So its possible so solve this problem with ratios but if there is any builtin function or a shorter way so let me know.